# Custom Widget for Wordpress to Enable marking Categories as “New!”

Tags: php, wordpress, widget, categories

Trying to build a widget for my simple wordpress blog, which will display categories in the sidebar, but not exactly like the native wordpress category widget. Basically, what I am trying to achieve is to be able to mark certain categories as "New!" or something similar, but from within the widget itself.

So far I have the following code that registers my widget and can display categories list in it on the backend with checkbox next to the name.

When I check the box and trying to save it it returns unchecked again. Not sure if my update function is actually working as serialized array in the DB has not changed on save.

Here is what I have do far:

```
/* CUSTOM BLOG CATEGORIES WIDGETS */
class Spr123_Categories_Widget extends WP_Widget {
    public function __construct() {
        $widget_options = array(
            'classname' => 'widget_custom_categories_widget',
            'description' => 'This is a Custom Blog Categories Widget',
        );
        parent::__construct( 'custom_categories_widget', 'Custom Categories Widget', $widget_options );
    }

    public function form( $instance ) {
        $title = ! empty( $instance['title'] ) ? $instance['title'] : '';
        $name = ! empty( $instance['name'] ) ? $instance['name'] : '';
        $checked = isset( $instance['checked'] ) ? (bool) $instance['checked'] : false;
        $categories = get_categories( array(
            'orderby' => 'name',
            'parent'  => 0,
            "hide_empty" => 0,
        ) );
        ?>
        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>">Title:</label>
            <input type="text" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>" class="widefat" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'title' ); ?>" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $title ); ?>" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="Categories">Categories:</label>
        </p>
        <?php print("<pre>".print_r($categories,true)."</pre>"); ?>
        <p>
        <?php
        foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
            ?>
            <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id($category->slug); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('checked'); ?>"<?php checked( $checked ); ?> />
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id($category->slug); ?>"><?php _e( 'Display as NEW - ' . esc_attr( $category->name )); ?></label><br />
            <?php
        }
        ?>
        </p>
        <?php

    }

    public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
        $instance = $old_instance;
        $instance[ 'title' ] = strip_tags( $new_instance[ 'title' ] );
        $instance[ 'name' ] = strip_tags( $new_instance[ 'name' ] );
        $instance[ 'checked' ] = !empty($new_instance['checked']) ? 1 : 0;
        return $instance;
    }

    public function widget( $args, $instance ) {

        $title = apply_filters( 'widget_title', $instance[ 'title' ] );
        $category_title = apply_filters( 'widget_title', $instance[ 'name' ] );

        echo $args['before_widget'] . $args['before_title'] . $title . $args['after_title']; ?>

        <p><?php echo $category_title ?></p>

        <?php echo $args['after_widget'];
    }

}
function spr123_custom_categories_widget() {
    register_widget( 'Spr123_Categories_Widget' );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'spr123_custom_categories_widget' );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
  /* CUSTOM BLOG CATEGORIES WIDGETS */
class Spr123_Categories_Widget extends WP_Widget {
    public function __construct() {
        $widget_options = array(
            'classname' => 'widget_custom_categories_widget',
            'description' => 'This is a Custom Blog Categories Widget',
        );
        parent::__construct( 'custom_categories_widget', 'Custom Categories Widget', $widget_options );
    }

    public function form( $instance ) {
        $title = ! empty( $instance['title'] ) ? $instance['title'] : '';
        $name = ! empty( $instance['name'] ) ? $instance['name'] : '';
        $checked = isset( $instance['checked'] ) ? (bool) $instance['checked'] : false;

        $savedcategories = ! empty( $instance['categories'] ) ? $instance['categories'] : '';

        $categories = get_categories( array(
            'orderby' => 'name',
            'parent'  => 0,
            "hide_empty" => 0,
        ) );
        ?>
        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>">Title:</label>
            <input type="text" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>" class="widefat" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'title' ); ?>" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $title ); ?>" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="Categories">Categories:</label>
        </p>
<!--        --><?php //print("<pre>".print_r($categories,true)."</pre>"); ?>
        <p>
        <?php
        foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
              $checked  = in_array($category->term_id, $savedcategories)?'checked':'';
            ?>
            <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id($category->slug); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('categories[]'); ?>" <?php echo $checked; ?> value="<?php echo $category->term_id; ?>"/>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id($category->slug); ?>"><?php echo esc_attr( $category->name ) . _e( 'Display as NEW - ' ); ?></label><br />
            <?php
        }
        ?>
        </p>
        <?php

    }

    public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
        $instance = $old_instance;
        $instance[ 'title' ] = strip_tags( $new_instance[ 'title' ] );
        $instance[ 'name' ] = strip_tags( $new_instance[ 'name' ] );        
        $instance[ 'categories' ] = $new_instance['categories'];       
        return $instance;
    }

    public function widget( $args, $instance ) {

        $title = apply_filters( 'widget_title', $instance[ 'title' ] );
        $category_title = apply_filters( 'widget_title', $instance[ 'name' ] );

        echo $args['before_widget'] . $args['before_title'] . $title . $args['after_title']; ?>

        <p><?php echo $category_title ?></p>

        <?php echo $args['after_widget'];
    }

}
function spr123_custom_categories_widget() {
    register_widget( 'Spr123_Categories_Widget' );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'spr123_custom_categories_widget' );
```

**you can the value in frontend by using this code**

```
   $widget_instances = get_option('widget_custom_categories_widget');

    print_r($widget_instances);
```

Comment: Vel, thank you , I think it is now working the way I need, just need to get few more things sorted on the output now. So the instance['name'] and $instance['checked'] are obsolete?

Comment: I didnt get you clearly. `So the instance['name'] and $instance['checked'] are obsolete?`?

Comment: this is no need `$checked = isset( $instance['checked'] ) ? (bool) $instance['checked'] : false;`

Comment: One more question, how should I manage the output, what I need is to have all categories on the front end with those checked shown as `<li><span style="color:red">New!</span> <a href="url" title="custom">Category Name</a></li>` and those that are not checked like so `<li><a href="url" title="custom">Category Name</a></li>`

Comment: Ok, I get everything from the widget this way, now all I need to do is to check the IDs and get everything else from `wp_list_categories();`